# Can i compare these two dates in JS?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log("201905300545_201905300555"  < "201905300535_201905300545")
```

How can i compare two dates in string format?

Comment: What do you mean by more? Do you mean the date range starts later? Ends later? Covers a greater period of time?

Comment: Which date? The start date? The end date? The median date?

Comment: You can split the strings around the `_` to get workable dates. You can then do as you please with them.

Comment: You can try `Date.parse()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse which with a little formatting love will turn your strings into actual JS date objects -- and then comparison operations become super easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the dates into `moment` and then use `moment`'s `diff` function to compare the durations, or dates, starts or ends, or any combination.

Your colleague's way of comparing the dates may be the fastest way in Javascript for the given use case of "Is the start date before the second start date and the end date before the second end date?"

```js
let s1 = "201905300545_201905300555";
let s2 = "201905300535_201905300545";
let m = t => moment(t,"YYYYMMDDhhmm");
let rng1 = s1.split("_").map(m);
let rng2 = s2.split("_").map(m);
console.log(rng1[1].diff(rng1[0]) < rng2[1].diff(rng2[0]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: typo here, `let rng2 = s1.split("_").map(m);` should be `let rng2 = s2.split("_").map(m);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get the range they are representing (by subtracting them):

```
 const range = r => {
   const [start, end] = r.split("_");
   return +end - +start;
 };

 console.log(range("201905300545_201905300555") < range("201905300535_201905300545"));
```

Comment: @popHip could you give an example of a case were it would not work?

Comment: In your example, if OP use 12-hour clock, 5:00am and 5:00pm will be represented the same way. So 6:00pm - 5:00am would be smaller range than 7:00am - 5:00am with your function ( what is wrong ). btw i did not downvote your answer since it match OP's example expected result, but it's always a bad idea to handle date with strings, every high level languages includes lib for that, use it !

Comment: If the OP uses a 12 hour clock, then no possible solution would work.

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, the format used here is not really explicit

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses only JavaScript :

```
let parseDate = (date => {
    let [l, year, month, day, hour, minute, ...r] = date.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/);
    return new Date(year, month-1, day, hour, minute);
});

let [d1, d2] = '201905300545_201905300555'.split('_').map(parseDate);
let [d3, d4] = '201905300535_201905300545'.split('_').map(parseDate);

console.log(d2 - d1 < d4 - d3);
```